# Echarts- Static bands using echarts

Tags: angular, echarts, apache-echarts

I am trying to create a functionality in [Apache Echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html) called static bands
where I am trying to change the background color of the graph based on the y-axis values.

Something like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIPGj.png)

So far I have tried using splitArea function and got the following result.

```
      splitArea:{
         show:true,
         areaStyle:{
          color:['green','blue','red']
          }
        }
    }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvi5i.png)

But I have not found any approach changing the background colors based on values using any methods in echarts.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [series-line.markArea](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markArea) is the way to go.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Distribution of Electricity',
    subtext: 'Fake Data'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross'
    }
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: true,
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    // prettier-ignore
    data: ['00:00', '01:15', '02:30', '03:45', '05:00', '06:15', '07:30', '08:45', '10:00', '11:15', '12:30', '13:45', '15:00', '16:15', '17:30', '18:45', '20:00', '21:15', '22:30', '23:45']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: '{value} W'
    },
    axisPointer: {
      snap: true
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Electricity',
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true,
      // prettier-ignore
      data: [300, 280, 250, 260, 270, 300, 550, 500, 400, 390, 380, 390, 400, 500, 600, 750, 800, 700, 600, 400],
      markArea: 
        {
        data: [
          [
            {
              name: 'Not good',
              yAxis: 100, // min of red area
              itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(255, 173, 177, 0.4)'
              },
            },
            {
              yAxis: 300,// max of red area
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              yAxis: 400,
              itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(55, 173, 77, 0.4)'
              },
            },
            {
              yAxis: 580
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              name: 'Very good',
              yAxis: 600,
              itemStyle: {
                color: 'rgba(55, 173, 177, 0.4)'
              },
            },
            {
              yAxis: 750
            }
          ],
        ]
      },
    }
  ]
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I hard-coded the min/max values but you can of course change them programmatically.